# moscow with user-stories

Tags: requirements, user-stories

I have adopted the user-story template introduced in [response to a question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707080/writing-user-stories-for-internal-technical-tasks), i.e.

```
AS A [person/role]
I NEED TO [do something] 
SO THAT [provides business value].
```

I have two questions:

1. How should I incorporate [MOSCOW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_Method) into user stories, which part of the template can / should change?
2. I am re-writing requirements and often deal with statements about content being available on a website. I am unsure whether I should write the user-story from the perspective of a website user reading the content, or ad administrator making the content available. Can anyone clarify the best approach to take?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: I don't have a preference either way, but there are a lot of non-programming tags on SO. Filter https://stackoverflow.com/tags for "agile", "scrum", "project-management", etc. I guess all questions with non-programming tags should also be closed, and the tags should be removed too?

Comment: That is true. I guess it will be gradually closed. Sometimes closed questions and tags get deleted via community efforts. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues

Answer (score 0):

MoSCoW is a requirement prioritization framework. Release and Roadmap planning would be the places to use it, along with prioritizing the User stories during backlog grooming.  As far as incorporating into individual User Stories, if a given User Story isn't the most valuable item to include in the next Release, why are you working on it now?

Regarding which user's perspective to use, use the one that offers the most valuable perspective. Perhaps consider writing 'what' stories from the 'user' perspective, and 'how' stories from the 'admin' (although there will be some 'what'-type stories for the admin persona.